# TCP sending segments timeout

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am working on a project that server using C which need to send heartbeat to client to check its status(using tcp socket)  and i am wondering how do server-side program detect whether the client has crashed.

to be exact, with tcp connection established, when server send a segment to client, it needs to get an ack reply,  what if the client has crashed, retransmit this segment over and over agian ? How do i handle this situation and could any one give me an example ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try the opposite way. Let the client sends requests to the server for an ack reply.

Answer (score 0):

When you design the protocol you are going to use in your project, you may do this any way you please. Generally, one side sends a message to the other every X seconds and the other side sends a reply. If the side that doesn't send the message doesn't receive a message in Y seconds (where Y is greater than X) it assumes the connection is dead.

Basically, you can do this any way you want if you are designing the protocol that goes on top of TCP. Just remember that TCP doesn't do this for you.